# Iphone SDK:[error]Cannot find protocol declaration for "NSNetServiceDelegate"

Tags: iphone, sdk

this code is from a sample
in .h part :

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController < NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate > {
        NSMutableArray * tableData;
        NSNetServiceBrowser * _browser;
        NSMutableArray * _foundServices;

        NSURLConnection * _connection;
        NSInputStream * _consumerStream;
        NSString * controllerHostName;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * tableData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNetServiceBrowser * _browser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * _foundServices;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection * connection;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInputStream * consumerStream;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * controllerHostName;
```

in the .m  part

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>

    @synthesize tableData;
    @synthesize _browser;
    @synthesize _foundServices;
    @synthesize consumerStream = _consumerStream;
    @synthesize connection = _connection;
    @synthesize controllerHostName;

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
            [super viewWillAppear:animated];

            _browser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
            [_browser setDelegate:self];
            [_browser searchForServicesOfType:@"_service._tcp" inDomain:@""];
            [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    }


    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
            [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

            [_browser stop];
            _browser.delegate = nil;
            [_browser release];
            _browser = nil;

            [_foundServices removeAllObjects];
    }
    - (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)netServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)netService moreComing:(BOOL)moreServicesComing
    {
            self.controllerHostName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", netService.name, netService.domain];
            NSLog(@"ControllerHost String is: %@", self.controllerHostName);
            NSLog(@"URL to use is === %@.%@", netService.name, netService.domain);
            if (!_foundServices) {
                    _foundServices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }

            [_foundServices addObject:netService];

            [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    - (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)netServiceBrowser didRemoveService:(NSNetService *)netService moreComing:(BOOL)moreServicesComing
    {
            [_foundServices removeObject:netService];
    }

    - (void)netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser
    {

        [_foundServices removeAllObjects];
}
```

I declaration all the header as the sample does
But I got error message "Cannot find protocol declaration for "NSNetServiceDelegate" 
in .h

```
interface ViewController : UITableViewController < NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate >
```

So did I missing anything to declaration ?
The sample doesn't has any warning or error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a unused function.  Just delete:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

It will be fine!

Answer (score 1):

I thought it's defined in "NSNetServices.h" instead?

Comment: That's weird...the apple references libary says : Declared In
NSNetServices.h,But I can't include or import it...

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your header:

```
#import <Foundation/NSNetServices.h>
```

I got this from the [BonjourWeb](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BonjourWeb/Introduction/Intro.html) Apple sample code project.

Comment: If you are saying you deleted the `< NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate >` part but still get the compilation error, then either you didn't save the file, or you are referencing `NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate` somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Oh I mean when I remove < NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate > ,It's ok no error,But It't won't find any service or return any Log(even it can't find)

Comment: It's there any relation about "Base SDK Missing" ?I update my xcode to 4.1 than the sdk was missing

Comment: Probably. Installing the 4.1 SDK removes the 4.0 SDK, and so you'll need to update the Base SDK build setting for your project.

Comment: I already done this...I can't select "Simulator" > "Debug" >SDK missing.But If I change to "Release" > it become Simulator - 3.2 |Release|...

Comment: You need to change the build setting across All Configurations.

Comment: I check the return data,Only _browser will return <NSNetServiceBrowser: 0x5f050a0>,other return null...so that means some void doesn't running ?

Answer (score 0):

I found something like answer ,JUST REMOVE

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [_browser stop];
    _browser.delegate = nil;
    [_browser release];
    _browser = nil;

    [_foundServices removeAllObjects];
}
```

The program will get Netservice I want...
WHY ?

Comment: I can see the console result:found service <NSNetService 0x4904f40> local. _envoservice._tcp. envo_eeepc
envoControllerHost String is: envo_eeepc.local
URL to use is === envo_eeepc.local.
ControllerHostName IS envo_eeepc.local.but simulator crash Immediately  ？？？？？？？？？？？？

Comment: To post more information, edit your question and add it there, instead of posting an answer.